# How to handle missing node in LINQ to XML query

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

The following example illustrates how to set a default value for a LINQ to XML query when data is missing:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons =
from e in x.Descendants("Person")
select new Person { 
    Name = e.Value,
    Age = (int?)e.Attribute("Age") ?? 21
};
```

But how do you handle when an attribute is missing altogether? For example what if the node has no parent node?

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons =
    from e in x.Descendants("Person")
    select new Person { 
        Name = e.Value,
        Age = (int?)e.Attribute("Age") ?? 21
        ParentAge = e.Parent.Attribute("Age")
    };
```

Comment: Hmm, `e` is selected with `x.Descendants("Person")` so it is going to have a `Parent` node. That parent node might not have the attribute you are looking for but at least with the sample you have posted the Parent node does exist.

Comment: I just don't understand this. When I comment out the ParentAge assignment above, it runs fine. Otherwise I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object error when evaluating the results of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You handle it the hard way, usually with the [ternary conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons =
    from e in x.Descendants("Person")
    select new Person { 
        Name = e.Value,
        Age = (int?) e.Attribute("Age") ?? 21,
        ParentAge = e.Parent != null ? (int) e.Parent.Attribute("Age") : 42
    };
```

To my knowledge, there is no shorter way to do that in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to check to see if a "Notes" node existed or not and handle both cases, as well as any apostrophes in the text strings (this code is used to create MySQL insert strings).  I enclose the string if it exists in single quotes and change any apostrophes to doubled, or simply insert a NULL if the node doesn't exist.  I have no control over the XML client that creates XML files, and I have literally tens of thousands of them to parse through, so this is what I came up with that works:

```
var items =
    from e in creationItems
    select new
    {
        //other values
        Notes = e.Descendants("Notes").Any() ? "'" + e.Descendants("Notes").First().Value.Replace("'", "''") + "'" : "NULL"
    };
```

I couldn't figure out how to add this properly as a comment, so this is just an adjunct to @Frédéric Hamidi's excellent answer.  This may be helpful to other folks in my predicament.  This reduces my parsing code by a large amount, so it's a great solution.